# Angular JS-$scope is undefined

Tags: angularjs

```
  $scope.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:57083/EntityService.asmx/InsertEntity",
            data: "{'Eno':'" + $scope.Eno + "','Ename':'" + $scope.Ename + "','DOB':'" + $scope.DOB + "','State':'" + $scope.State + "','City':'" + $scope.City + "','pin':'" +
            $scope.pin + "','mobile':'" + $scope.mobile + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (responseData) {
                alert(responseData.d);
            },
            error: function (responseData) {
                alert(responseData.d);
            }

        });
    };
```

In this Code i am trying to connect with database using angular JS. But it is not working,it shows error as "$scope" is undefined.Can anyone explain?

Comment: Please show more code. Usually `$scope` needs to be injected into your controller which itself should be bound to a module representing (part of) your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $.ajax use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service:

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://localhost:57083/EntityService.asmx/InsertEntity',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=utf-8"
 },
 data: "{'Eno':'" + $scope.Eno + "','Ename':'" + $scope.Ename + "','DOB':'" + $scope.DOB + "','State':'" + $scope.State + "','City':'" + $scope.City + "','pin':'" +
            $scope.pin + "','mobile':'" + $scope.mobile + "'}",
}

$http(req).success(function(responseData)
{ alert(responseData.d);
})
.error(function(responseData){
 alert(responseData.d);
});
```

*you need to inject $http service in controller the same way as you have injected $scope now.*

Comment: You are using $http or $.ajax.?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error when a module has not been injected in the reference area of the controller i.e.

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  ...
}]);
```

Comment: Actuallly,I  am new in angular js .Can you explain how can i make changes into this code.Or is there any other way to do it.Whatever i have shown in this code i have written it in separate js file.